# How to use jquery IF statement instead of FOR

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a request to sqlite and receiving data with the following code:

```
var rows = results.rows;
        alert(rows.length);
        for (var index = 0; index < rows.length; index++) {
            var x = rows.item(index);
            $('body').append(x.id + ',' + x.username + ',' + x.time + ',' + x.distance);
        }
```

But how to check and alert if there is 0 rows, I mean no data in the table?

Should it be???:

```
var rows = results.rows;
if(rows.length===0) { alert('nothing in DB');
} else {
 var x = rows.item(index);
 $('body').append(x.id + ',' + x.username + ',' + x.time + ',' + x.distance);
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Check if `rows.length` is 0.

Comment: Um `if(rows.length===0)...`

Comment: Sorry if I sound stupid but just a beginner and need an an example. Thank you in advance

Comment: There is no such thing as a jQuery `if` statement. JavaScript is the language which specifies the behavior of `if`. jQuery is a library built using JavaScript.

Comment: @epascarello for (i=0; i =<0; i++) it simply will not iterate  :)

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio _"how to check and alert if there is 0 rows"_ <- the for loop won't do that by itself though

Comment: ahah, touché  :) I didn't read that part of the question

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio **"But how to check and alert if there is 0 rows"** Um how is a for loop going to do that?

Comment: @epascarello got it mate :D

Answer (score 1):

In order to check the absence of rows in your result set, it should be enough to use `rows.length`, like this:

```
if (rows.length === 0) {
    alert("There are no rows.");
}
```

Comment: just use if(row.length) to check 0 or 1 , true or false . If condition will take care about it

Comment: `if (rows.length)` would check the opposite; the contained code would be executed if there were rows. You could write `if (!rows.length)` to get the desired behavior, but I would rather be more explicit considering the nature of the question.

Answer (score 0):

the cool thing about FOR cycles: if rows.length = 0 (you got no rows back from the DB) the FOR cycle won't iterate not even 1 time :)

Comment: Thank you @GrafiCodeStudio Sorry if I sound stupid but just a beginner and need an an example. Thank you in advance